Which kind of non-linear component is required for a differential equation in order to show frequency mixing?
Which kind of non-linear component is required for a differential equation in order to show frequency mixing?
I going to focus the question on the electromagnetic wave equation as an example, by I am asking the question in general for Ordinary and Partial Differential Equations. This because for me is simple to explain which phenomena I am interesting about with an optics' example. Please notice I am interested in understand how to model these kind of phenomena from the mathematical point of view, looking to understand which tools I can use for it, and I am not asking about the physics behind the mentioned examples.
Intro______________
I am aware that when I use Linear differential equations, for them is not possible to represent a solution or an excitation on some specific initial frequency $w_0$ and show later results on other solution modes in another frequencies, let say $w_1$.
This translates in the Electromagnetic wave equation example $\nabla u = \frac{1}{c^2}u_{tt}$, that if I have some laser beam of some specific color $w_0$ (let say green), and it is going to be modulated by a thin grid hologram, which can be thought as a structure made by a linear differential equation, the incoming beam would excite one of their constituent modes as solution at the output, the diffracted beam would be also of the same color green (but its direction/shape/polarization/linear-angular-orbital-momentums could have changed).
But these kind of linear differential equations would never been able to model, as example, the phenomenon that happens when a green laser pointer is directed to a transparent glass filled with olive oil, where one could see in the oil a trace made by a red beam of light due fluorescence effects (check the video of the experiment here): a nonlinear term is required in order to model this phenomenon with a differential equation.
Question___________
I am asking which kind of nonlinear components are required on a differential equation (scenario 1: ODEs / scenario 2: PDEs), in order to be able to model these kind of frequency changing/mixing behaviors? (not meaning here in the mentioned olive oil example the original beam have changed color, but instead some extra process with a different color is needed to be incorporated - but a changing color additional term is also welcomed as answers)... Would it be a quadratic additional term $u^2$? Or a non-Lipschitz component like $\text{sgn}(u')$? Maybe a ratio $1/u$? Will it require to have complex-valued coefficients? Hope you get my question.
As example, if I review these Wikipedia pages List of nonlinear ordinary differential equations and List of nonlinear partial differential equations, I would like to know if it possible to figure out from its form if it allows these kind of frequency mixing phenomena to be part of their solutions. Also examples would be welcomed.
Or otherwise, if its impossible for a differential equation to model these kind of frequency mixing phenomena, please explain why or give a reference where it is demonstrated.

Update 1
Thanks for the answer by @whpowell96 I kind of have a revelation I would like share so you could verify its validity: in the answer it is explained like a quadratic term $u^2$ will introduce harmonics of the original frequency of the monochromatic excitation $k_0$, now in my own interpretation, thinking in a Fourier series decomposition, it would show many multiplication of trigonometric functions like the example used in the answer $2\sin^2(x) = 1+\sin(2x)$, so in principle, only harmonics of the original components would happen.
This should not be a problem due the magic of adding infinite harmonics lead to almost all well behaved functions (Fourier decomposition), but somehow it also could be a modeling limitation. Think in an arbitrary nonlinear component $F(u)$, if it admits a Taylor series expansion, then it is equivalent to a sum of polynomials $a_k u^k$, so again, the only possible results are harmonic combinations: if I take infinite terms is not an issue, but if instead I choose a truncated version of the Taylor expansion then it must have only harmonics terms into the response/solution, which could be a modeling limitation thinking for example on Second order approximations or Perturbation theory.
On the other hand, there are still nonlinear terms to explore which cannot be represented as power series, as example, non analytic functions. The only example I am aware of it is considering a Non-Lipschitz component such uniqueness could be broken, introducing singular solutions, that allows to have solutions that achieve by itself a rest position in finite time: a dissipative system where in a finite extinction time $T<\infty$ solutions could be stitched with the trivial zero solution, which cannot be achievable with a non-piecewise power series solution since it would violate the Identity theorem  (check these papers for details paper 1 paper 2).
As an example of the last kind could be the one I reviewed in this previous question: a brick sliding with classic friction after an initial push $x''=-k\ g\ \text{sgn}(x')$, which if I didn't messed it up have as solution $x(t)= \frac{x(0)}{4}\ \left(1-\frac{t}{T}+\left|1-\frac{t}{T}\right|\right)^2$ which holds uniqueness between $[0,\ T)$ and after it becomes $x(t)=0,\ \forall t\geq T$. Since $x(t)$ it is squared-integrable and compact-supported, by the Paley–Wiener theorem its spectrum should be an entire function, so a Non-Lipschitz dissipative term like $-\text{sgn}(u')$ that creates a system which is able to achieve a rest position in finite time would be introducing a continuous range frequencies.
Hope you could review if these two considerations are true, and also if you know other alternatives, present them with an example.

The Fourier convolution theorem implies that any power of $u$ is sufficient to mix frequencies. I imagine this then generalizes to analytic nonlinearities

@whpowell96 Thanks for commenting. Could you elaborate please? I don't understand if you mean that the diff. eqn. should include a term like $u(t)\circledast u(t)$? Or instead, you mean that every linear diff. eqn. should be able already since it response is a convolution? The later don't look right for me with my current knowledge, since it kind of goes against the Superposition principle, and at least the wiki for non-linear optics is presented as where color-change phenomena rises

The Fourier convolution theorem implies that
$$
\mathcal{F}[u^2](k) = [\hat{u}*\hat{u}](k).
$$
This immediately demonstrates frequency mixing for nonconstant $u$. Indeed, if $\hat{u}$ is supported only around a single frequency $k_0$, this shows that the frequency content of $u^2$ will have support near $0$, $k_0$, and $2k_0$. This can be seen explicitly in the case of $2\sin^2(x)= 1+\sin2x$. Similar mixing occurs in all higher powers of $u$.

Thanks for the answer. I saw the Wiki for non-linear optics and many descriptions are quadratic, and as you mentioned, non-linearities are always multiples of the incoming frequency $w_0$ (harmonics). Now if I have some nonlinear operator $F(u)$ and I could use its Taylor expansion, since all terms would be polynomials, this would tell that the only possible frequency mixes are related to harmonics of $w_0$, which is somehow a hard restriction (tells you frequencies would be quantized for every nonlinear diff. eqn., and it don't sounds true). Do you know some continious mixinging term?

I don't think this says that the solution of a differential equation will have quantized frequencies, just that one part of the equation will be quantized specifically when it operates on a pure wave signal. It may still be the case that the solution to some PDE $Lu = F(u)$ must have continuous spectra

I think they do exist, a dissipative system that stop moving requires, at least in the math, infinite frequencies, since the Paley-Wiener Theorem tells you a compact-supported fn has an entire fn as spectra, but these kind of finite duration systems must have a non-Lipschitz term on the differential equation (like $\text{sgn}(u)$), and physics and math have widely avoid using these kind of diff. eqns., so I am trying to see if there are alternatives (just see here how people downvoted the symplest example I could think of).
